# Switch 'Prefer 32-bit' Option Based on the Setup Project Target Platform

Tags: 32bit-64bit, setup-project

I have an application with two separate installer projects for x86 and x64 platforms. They reference sqlite3.dll and sqlite_x64.dll respectively. The problem is that when I build the x86 setup project, I have to switch the 'Prefer 32 bit' flag on manually for other projects. Isn't there any elegant way of managing this automatically? I found that its possible to remove the flag programmatically using this command:

```
CorFlags.exe MyApplication.exe /32BITPREF-
```

but I don't want to write too much of an ugly code. One option would be to pass a parameter to notify the project installer which platform the application is going to set up against and based on it's value run the above command in it's install event. But I hope there's some simpler and 'cleaner' option for achieving this.

Comment: The automatic way would be a post-build step in your build, to alter the exe before the setup project is built. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Sounds good. I was considering another option as well - to create .bat files to build the setup projects with the correct configuration. Thanks for the advice.